# How can I style React Router elements with styled-jsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, styled-jsx

I have a react-router element `<NavLink/>` that I am trying to style with the styled-jsx library. However, the css properties I apply to its className don't have any effect. Styling normal jsx elements works perfectly fine. Does anyone know if there is another way I can style this element (I want to set `text-decoration: none`). If possible I would like to avoid inline styles.

Here is my simplified code:

```
const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">
        Home
      </NavLink>

      <style jsx>
        {`
          .nav-link {
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you already using `styled-jsx` in your project and you specifically need to get it working? Or are you asking generally how to style React components *outside* of using a `style` prop? There are many options for styling React components.